# How to generate random values for a predefined function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, statistics

I have a predefined function, for example this:

```
my_func = lambda x: (9 * math.exp((-0.5 * y) / 60))/1000
```

How can I generate random values against it so I can plot the results of the function using `matplotlib`?

Comment: With `math.exp` you have to provide `my_func` with single values.  However, as written, your function is not right.  You use `x` as the argument, but `y` in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot, don't use random x values but rather a range.

Also you should use `numpy.exp` that can take a vector as input and your `y` in the lambda should be `x` (`y` is undefined).

This gives us:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_func = lambda x: (9 * np.exp((-0.5 * x) / 60))/1000

xs = np.arange(-1000,10)

plt.plot(xs, my_func(xs))
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do, but the `random` module is where you want to search. For example, testing it with 100 values between 0 and 1:

```
import random
my_func = lambda y: (9 * math.exp((-0.5 * y) / 60))/1000
values = [my_func(random.random()) for _ in range(100)]
```

Or the same thing with 1000 integers between 50 and 250:

```
import random
my_func = lambda y: (9 * math.exp((-0.5 * y) / 60))/1000
values = [my_func(random.randint(50, 250)) for _ in range(1000)]
```

The module's documentaion might help: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

The same thing could be achieved with `numpy` for large datasets, but again, it depends on what exactly you need here

P.S I corrected your `lambda` to actually use the `y` value instead of `x`, i assume it's just a typo

Comment: @Mark you are right, I've added a small correction to that